# How to store days of the week in Core Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data

I am developing an app that uses alarms to notify the user of an event and I need to give the user the option of choosing which days the alarm should be applied.
To do this I have provided the user with 7 check boxes (one for each day) and I've already established that the check boxes are going to be linked to booleans, however I cannot work out how these should be stored.

I am using core data to store these alarms. I had thought I could use an array however core data does not allow me to store arrays in the data model.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6):

You have plenty of options. You can use a 7-digit bitfield mask like:

```
BOOL monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday;
int bitmask = 0;
bitmask |= monday << 0;
bitmask |= tuesday << 1;
bitmask |= wednesday << 2;
bitmask |= thursday << 3;
bitmask |= friday << 4;
bitmask |= saturday << 5;
bitmask |= sunday << 6;
```

Or you could just store a table of 7 BOOLs.

Answer (score 2):

The bitmask idea is quite smart, but you could also have an entity weekday. Then you create 7 objects of that entity. Establish a relation between your alarms and those weekdays if needed. This has the advantage that you can define a reverse relation and query easily for the alarms to go off on a certain weekday.